# How can we draw 3D bulding structure from existing image Jquery,Css?

Tags: jquery, css, three.js, webgl

Please see this site it was made in flash:
Can we do it by jquery css?

[Go here](http://tain-con.com/Property_details.aspx?a=Residential&b=India&c=Pune&d=Fatima%20Nagar&e=Indian%20Rupees&f=1&g=Tain%20Square&h=buy&i=fetured&mm=10000000000)

And click on any building marked with "Release"
You will see one building on hover animation effect.
That i want to develop using jquery and css 
Or you can suggest for development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First you need to know there is nothing 3d here. These are pre-rendered images. You draw these highlighted areas in a software as different layer, photoshop for example.

[image]

2. Then you need create an area that can detect mouse hover. The old school [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) html markup is one way to do this.  You will draw a polygon that covers the same area as your highlight images.

[image]

The result will be something like this:

```
<map name="image-maps-2015-02-15-031753" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-02-15-031753">
    <area alt="" href="#" title="" shape="poly" coords="52,99,101,49,172,21,267,21,317,93,302,127,268,63,194,73,129,89,74,115,49,132" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
</map>
```

3. finally, you need a bit JS to do "**if mouse hover the area, show the highlight image**" . In the case you use jquery, mouseenter event on map is simple enough to do this;

   $('map').on('mouseenter', function () {
       $('#highlight').show();
   })

   $('map').on('mouseleave', function () {
       $('#highlight').hide();
   })

---

FULL DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pggyq4t8/2/  (hover the top floor)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have highlighted floors as you have done in your example. But main issue is that when you hover on any floor. It should like 3D as I have mentioned link in my Question comments...In that what happening is that, on hover of any floor whole floor should be highlighted and other floors should be fogged and create look like 3D and then color should also be transperant.So,It seems like 3D. Please check Link of my question

Comment: @user2982644 Hi, that's just another image of building, rendered differently with the same 3d software.  When hover, show this image above the original one. See this new example: http://jsfiddle.net/pggyq4t8/3/

Answer (score 0):

May 2020, in my answer on a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099505), I showed the OP in my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62101723/2015909) how to use an SVG file instead and have much more control over the image overlay and use a CSS only solution (with `<a>` and some demo text showing on `:hover`). I also made the HTML page fully responsive for use on varying devices.

Posting the code snippet here only (go 'Full page' for a better look. Resize browser to test responsiveness):

```css
/*
    Visit below answers on Stackoverflow for an explanation
    of the math used for responsive sizing of elements.

    https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033317/2015909
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/61867702/2015909
*/
/**************************/
/* preferred global rules */
/**************************/
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }
body                    { margin: 0 }

/* responsive base font size using y = mx + b */
html    { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) } /* (320,14)(1280,20) */
body    { font-size: 1rem }

[band]  { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; align-content: center }

[padded="1"], [padded="0"] [band*="padded"] {
/*
    responsive page padding
    and responsive band padding (same as responsive page padding, but at band level)
    p1(320,32) p2(1920, 72) => 0.025x + 24
    p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 

    'Band padding' is only active when 'page padding' is off 
*/
    padding: calc( 2.5vh + 24px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);
}

/* Making sure the image fits in any viewport, either portrait or landscape */
@media (orientation: portrait ) { #construction-site { height: auto; width: 100% } }
@media (orientation: landscape) { #construction-site { height: 100%; width: auto } }
</style>
```

```html
<body padded="0">
<div id="construction-site" band="padded">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 1600 1200"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

        <style>
            .line       { stroke: Black; stroke-opacity: 0; stroke-width: 2px; cursor: pointer } 
            .polyline   { fill  : Red  ; fill-opacity  : 0 }
    
            .floor-text { fill: Black; stroke: none; fill-opacity: 0; cursor: default;
                          font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;
                          /* responsive font using y = mx + b */
                          font-size: calc(-1vmin + 51.2px); /* (320,48)(1920,32) */
                        }

            .floor:hover>.line       { fill-opacity: .4; stroke-opacity: .8 }
            .floor:hover+.floor-text { fill-opacity: .7 }
        </style>

        <image href="https://i.imgur.com/0i4N0d3.jpg"/>

        <a id="top-floor" class="floor" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0)" title="top floor, click for details...">
            <polyline class="line polyline" 
                points="201.242,678.473 1121.43, 333.16 1370.24,
                        553.473 1387.74, 668.473 1127.49,
                        474.098 189.242, 753.473 202.242, 678.973"/>

            <line class="line" x1="1121.42" y1="333.472" x2="1127.45" y2="474.097"/>

        </a>
        <text class="floor-text" x="800" y="150" text-anchor="middle">top floor demo text</text>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
```